# Does food microwaved in a fleishig microwave become fleishigs?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher

If a person warms up soup which itself contains no meat in a microwave that is normally used for meat would this soup have the same status as meat and cause the person who ate it to be required to wait the same amount of time as eating meat?

Comment: How is this different from soup with no meat made in a meat pot?

Comment: @DoubleAA isn't it different? If you microwave a bowl of parve soup in a plastic bowl, does the soup become fleishig? (assuming the microwave is clean but normally used for meat). With pots you have *blyiot*, not so with microwaves. I'm not challenging, just asking, as I thought there would be no issue. I know for sure that if the bowl is covered (plastic sheet), there is no issue

Comment: @mbloch The OP asked if the soup would make you need to wait or if it just can't be eaten with milk. The microwave is no worse than the pot which only makes the soup unable to be eaten with milk. (You're right that there are reasons to think a microwave is more lenient and may never become "meat". But the OP is working with the stringent opinions that microwaves can have a food-gender.)

Comment: @therxv These questions depend on many criteria which is why they are normally best asked to a rav who can ask for clarifications. In the spirit of helping though: if you are asking *a priori* for ways to make it possible, then you could heat the soup in a parve/plastic container, cover it with plastic, and be reassured the soup doesn't make you fleishig. This assumes the soup was parve to start with and the microwave is clean. If you ask after the fact, then it doesn't matter since 22 hours elapsed from your question :->

Comment: Voted to close because it's best that these questions are directed to a competent Orthodox Rav.

Comment: @ezra I disagree. If you feel that way, well, feel free to close every [tag:halacha] question. As this is presently worded, there is nothing indicating being practical Halacha and I vote to keep it open.